# Why was my edit (adding example code) rejected as "It should have been written as a comment or an answer"

Tags: support

I made an edit to [An answer on my own question - "Why is Path.GetFileName(string) returning the full path?"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8863629) adding example code to the answer. So that if someone comes across this problem in the future they will have some code that they can use.

This edit was done to help people but was rejected unanimously as:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer

I can't understand why.

- If I write a C# method as a comment it will be poorly formatted and practically useless.
- I felt editing the already correct (but in my opinion could be improved upon) answer was better than writing my own answer with code and marking that as correct instead.

So why was my edit rejected? What is the best way to add this example code to my question for others to see and use?

Comment: Both of your questions are answered in the rejection reason. That was a huge change that certainly shouldn't have been an edit. You don't have to mark your own answer as correct if you do write one, and you could have commented asking the answerer if they would welcome your changes (they can then unilaterally accept it).

Comment: Why is it seen as better to write another answer rather than improve on an already correct one that is not fully explained? Are edits there to improve answers or merely fix typos? By rejecting the edit the quality of the answer has been decreased. Surely that's not correct?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing, your suggestion went well beyond the bullet points there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had that edit in my review queue and I skipped because I was in doubt, I'd reject that edit not because of its quality but because of its intent.

Yes undoubtedly you improved that answer but you also make it something *different*. It can't be rejected because *it clearly conflicts with author's intent* and for sure is not a *minor edit* but from help center we know that an edit *should be*:

- To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
- To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
- To **include additional information only found in comments**, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
- To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
- To add related resources or hyperlinks

However help center also says:

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and **up-to-date**.

To keep an answer up-to-date may imply to add much content, that's where my doubt came from.

In general for *new material* you'd better post a new answer (if your material is enough to have dignity of answer). It also has an advantage: you will have attribution for information you provide.

Comment: In my opinion I think my edit came under bullet point 2. But it seems the general consensus is to write a new answer. And like you said the advantage being I will have attribution for the information.

Comment: @user1 personally I interpret "clarify" as _to make an obscure or convoluted answer more clear without adding_ more _information_ but maybe it's just POV.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I have now added a separate answer. I think the questions is for quite an unusual problem that people may encounter in the future so wanted to make the answers as clear as possible